# Design pattern to implement an iterative fallback mechanism

Tags: java, android

I have written a word definition fetcher that parses web pages from a dictionary website.
Not all web pages have exactly the same HTML structure, so I had to implement several parsing methods to support the majority of cases.

Below is what I have done so far, which is pretty ugly code.

**What do you think would be the cleanest way of coding some kind of iterative fallback mechanism** (there may be a more appropriate term), so that I can implement N ordered parsing methods (parsing failures must trigger the next parsing method, whereas exceptions such as IOException should break the process) ?

```
    public String[] getDefinition(String word) {
    String[] returnValue = { "", "" };
    returnValue[0] = word;
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        String finalUrl = String.format(_baseUrl, word);
        Connection con = Jsoup.connect(finalUrl).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.1; en-us; Nexus One Build/ERD62) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
        doc = con.get();
        // *** Case 1 (parsing method that works for 80% of the words) ***
        String basicFormOfWord = doc.select("DIV.luna-Ent H2.me").first().text().replace("·", "");
        String firstPartOfSpeech = doc.select("DIV.luna-Ent SPAN.pg").first().text();
        String firstDef = doc.select("DIV.luna-Ent DIV.luna-Ent").first().text();

        returnValue[1] = "<b>" + firstPartOfSpeech + "</b><br/>" + firstDef;
        returnValue[0] = basicFormOfWord;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        try {
            // *** Case 2 (Alternate parsing method - for poorer results) ***
            String basicFormOfWord = doc.select("DIV.results_content p").first().text().replace("·", "");
            String firstDef = doc.select("DIV.results_content").first().text().replace(basicFormOfWord, "");

            returnValue[1] = firstDef;
            returnValue[0] = basicFormOfWord;
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: you can consider the Chain of Responsibility[Pattern](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/chains.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain of Responsibility, as already noted, is a good candidate.
John's answer OTOH does not feature a chain of responsibility in the proper sense, since an UrlParser does not actively decide whether to handle the request to the next parser.
Here's my trivial shot at it:

```
public class ParserChain {
    private ArrayList<UrlParser> chain = new ArrayList<UrlParser>();
    private int index = 0;
    public void add(UrlParser parser) {
        chain.add(parser);
    }
    public String[] parse(Document doc) throws IOException {
        if (index = chain.size()){
            return null;
        }
        return chain.get(index++).parse(doc);
    }
}

public interface UrlParser {
    public String[] parse(Document doc, ParserChain chain) throws IOException;
}

public abstract class AbstractUrlParser implements UrlParser {
    @Override
    public String[] parse(Document doc, ParserChain chain) throws IOException {
        try {
            return this.doParse(doc);
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            return chain.parse(doc);
        }
    }
    protected abstract String[]  doParse(Document doc) throws ParseException, IOException;
}
```

Notable things:

- This code keeps a stack frame for ParserChain#parse and one for UrlParser#parse for every parser it enters, until some parser stops the chain of responsibility. If you have huge chains, you could run in a stack overflow (how appropriate)
- an UrlParser that does not extend AbstractUrlParser can modify the argument String and than delegate the next in chain, or delegate the next in chain and then modify the result.
- the ParserChain is not thread-safe (but I'd say this is something inherent to the Chain Of Responsibility pattern)

Edit: corrected code as of Sebastien's comment

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll stick to your proposal. I believe the last return statement should be `return chain.parse(doc);` though.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [Chain-of-Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)- like pattern. I would have the following:

```
public interface UrlParser(){
     public Optional<String[]> getDefinition(String word) throws IOException;
}

public class Chain{
    private List<UrlParser> list;

    @Nullable
    public String[] getDefinition(String word) throws IOException{
         for (UrlParser parser : list){
             Optional<String[]> result = parser.getDefinition(word);
             if (result.isPresent()){
                return result.get();
             }
         }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am using Guava's `Optional` here but you could return a `@Nullable` from the interface as well. Then define a class for each URL parser you need and inject them into `Chain`